# How to make a block of text disappear when a bootstrap site goes to mobile/ falls below a certain pixel width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

We have a website using bootstrap, css, and html. we have a piece of text that we want to disappear when on mobile.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get helpful answers, please include the code you have tried so far to solve this problem so we can help you debug or improve it.

Answer (score 1):

There are slightly different classes you need to add depending on the version of Bootstrap, e.g. `hidden-sm-down` for v4-alpha (https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/)